# multicast listener efficiency

Tags: multicast

Currently I have a process listening and processing a multicast data stream. I'm thinking about seperate it into two processes, one listening, one processing, both will subscribe to the multicast traffic. 
my question is, will this lower the efficiency because now there are two listener to the multicast stream?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing more work so by definition it is going to be less efficient.  The better question is whether it really matters, and the answer is probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you make it the way that the listening process will be restarting the processing process in case of crash it makes sense.
It will not be less efficient as you have already two listeners.`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this will be less efficient since the kernel will have to make a copy of each datagram to each socket listening to the multicast group.